# how to launch InAppBrowser as soon as app opens - IONIC

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I really need help. I want my InAppBrowser to launch as soon as i open my App.

I have already tried a lot of things but i'm new in Ionic and don't have much idea why the code in the "header" section isn't working. like it normally would in a website.

How do i do that??

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).